# Empty Modal PopUp in Sitecore

Tags: html, sitecore, sitecore8, modalpopup

I'm working on displaying a Richtext in MVC Sitecore View.

Below is my code

```
<div class="modal-body">
@Html.Sitecore().Field("{ACBE8753-2970-****-A022-4C4******4AA}")
</div>
```

When I click on Modal pop up link, I see its empty (below is screenshot). Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

When I put simple HTML content. Its working. But, Rich text or simple text is not working in Modal Pop up:

[image]

Comment: Even that doesn't work sadly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of wrong HTML references. Nothing wrong with Sitecore.

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.Sitecore().Field()` method does NOT accept field ID (guid) as parameter.

Options are:

```cs
public virtual HtmlString Field(string fieldName)
public virtual HtmlString Field(string fieldName, object parameters)
public virtual HtmlString Field(string fieldName, Item item)
public virtual HtmlString Field(string fieldName, Item item, object parameters)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Above are method definitions. Use e.g.:

```
<div class="modal-body">
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Modal Content")
</div>
```

where `Modal Content` is replaced with whatever your field name (with guid `{ACBE8753-2970-****-A022-4C4******4AA}`) is.

Comment: Hi Merek,
So, here we are not using any server side programming. We have to stick to client side options.

Answer (score 0):

You can get item like this:

```
 var item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("your item ID or your path ID")
```

Display your richtext field:

```
 @Html.Sitecore().Field("name of your richtext field", item)
```